# Difference between "thread-safe data" vs "thread-safe code/functions"

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, concurrency, thread-safety

I stumbled across these terms as I was studying thread-safety but didn't get a clear picture. What is the difference between thread-safe data and thread-safe code/function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`thread-safe data`: data that can not be corrupted (due to wrong thread code).

`thread-safe code/function`: code that prevents shared data to be corrupted. All threads in a proccess share the same memory data.

How to prevent corruption? It comes when two threads are trying to modify the same data at once (concurrent reads are safe). Techniques to prevent are "mutex", "semaphores" and "conditional variables". See [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).